# Hibernate Criteria for Dates

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee, criteria

In oracle I have dates in format

17-April-2011 19:20:23.707000000

I would like to retrieve all orders for 17-04-2011.

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
String myDate = "17-04-2011";
Date date = formatter.parse(myDate);
    Criteria criteria = 
                session.createCriteria(Order.class);
Criterion restrictDate = Restrictions.like("orderDate",date);
```

but it brings me empty result:

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Why do you use `Restrictions.like(...`)?

You should use `Restrictions.eq(...)`.

Note you can also use `.le`, `.lt`, `.ge`, `.gt` on date objects as comparison operators. `LIKE` operator is not appropriate for this case since `LIKE` is useful when you want to match results according to partial content of a column.
Please see http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-LIKE.asp for the reference.

For example if you have a name column with some people's full name, you can do `where name like 'robert %'` so that you will return all entries with name starting with `'robert '` (`%` can replace any character).

In your case you know the full content of the date you're trying to match so you shouldn't use `LIKE` but equality. I guess Hibernate doesn't give you any exception in this case, but anyway you will probably have the same problem with the `Restrictions.eq(...)`.

Your date object you got with the code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
String myDate = "17-04-2011";
Date date = formatter.parse(myDate);
```

This date object is equals to the 17-04-2011 at 0h, 0 minutes, 0 seconds and 0 nanoseconds.

This means that your entries in database must have **exactly** that date. What i mean is that if your database entry has a date "17-April-2011 19:20:23.707000000", then it won't be retrieved because you just ask for that date: "17-April-2011 00:00:00.0000000000".

If you want to retrieve all entries of your database from a given day, you will have to use the following code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
    String myDate = "17-04-2011";
    // Create date 17-04-2011 - 00h00
    Date minDate = formatter.parse(myDate);
    // Create date 18-04-2011 - 00h00 
    // -> We take the 1st date and add it 1 day in millisecond thanks to a useful and not so known class
    Date maxDate = new Date(minDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
    Conjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();
    // The order date must be >= 17-04-2011 - 00h00
    and.add( Restrictions.ge("orderDate", minDate) );
    // And the order date must be < 18-04-2011 - 00h00
    and.add( Restrictions.lt("orderDate", maxDate) );
```

Comment: Note that it is important to understand that when you parse a date it may be important to think about the timezone in which you want to parse/format the Java Date

Answer (score 4):

By using this way you can get the list of selected records.

```
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
Criteria cri = session.createCriteria(ProjectActivities.class);
cri.add(Restrictions.ge("EffectiveFrom", gregorianCalendar.getTime()));
List list = cri.list();
```

All the Records will be generated into list which are greater than or equal to '08-Oct-2012' or else pass the date of user acceptance date at 2nd parameter of Restrictions (`gregorianCalendar.getTime()`) of criteria to get the records.

Answer (score 3):

If the column is a timestamp you can do the following:

```
        if(fromDate!=null){
            criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("TRUNC(COLUMN) >= TO_DATE('" + dataFrom + "','dd/mm/yyyy')"));
        }
        if(toDate!=null){               
            criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("TRUNC(COLUMN) <= TO_DATE('" + dataTo + "','dd/mm/yyyy')"));
        }

        resultDB = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
    String dateStr = "17-April-2011 19:20:23.707000000 ";
    Date dateForm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(dateStr);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");  

    String newDate = format.format(dateForm);  

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date fromDate = format.parse(newDate);
    today.setTime(fromDate);
    today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    Date toDate= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(format.format(today.getTime()));

    Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Model.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.ge("dateFieldName", fromDate));
    crit.add(Restrictions.le("dateFieldName", toDate));
    return crit.list();
```