# How to match date value to a column which has timestamp values in Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: hibernate, date, timestamp, criteria

I want to match date `2014-08-26` value to a column(called update_date) which has timestamp datatype.

```
Criteria criteria=createEntityCriteria(Order.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("updatedDate",transactionDate1));
```

When I used above code it does not return any thing because of data type mismatch.

```
select * from order_master where security_id=2 and client_master_id=3 and update_date="2014-08-26 19:04:14";
```

Above query returns exact result.Main Problem is I Only have the data `2014-08-26` but not update time.
Please let me know what should I do to get the correct result in `Hibernate Criteria`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this post --> [Hibernate Criteria for Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790602/hibernate-criteria-for-dates)

As per this post you cannot use `Restrictions.eq()` or `Restrictions.like()` for comparing dates.

Here is the code that works for you:

To compare dates between 2 ranges:

```
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        String startDateStr = "18-08-2014";
        String endDateStr = "27-08-2014";

        Date startDate = formatter.parse(startDateStr);
        Date endDate = formatter.parse(endDateStr);

        List<Order> orders = session.createCriteria(Order.class)
                .add(Restrictions.between("updatedDate", startDate, endDate))
                .list();
        for (Order order : orders) {
            System.out.println(order.getUpdatedDate());
        }
```

If you want to get records for a single day then you can replace the field `endDate` with:

```
Date endDate = new Date(minDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like below

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
    String myDate = "17-04-2011";
    // Create date 17-04-2011 - 00h00
    Date minDate = formatter.parse(myDate);
    // Create date 18-04-2011 - 00h00 
    // -> We take the 1st date and add it 1 day in millisecond thanks to a useful and not so known class
    Date maxDate = new Date(minDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
    Conjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();
    // The order date must be >= 17-04-2011 - 00h00
    and.add( Restrictions.ge("orderDate", minDate) );
    // And the order date must be < 18-04-2011 - 00h00
    and.add( Restrictions.lt("orderDate", maxDate) );
```