# Hibernate and HSQLDB - criteria sql restrictions for dates

Tags: java, hibernate, date, hsqldb, hibernate-criteria

I am using JavaFX, Hibernate and HSQLDB in my project.

In my DAOIMPL classes I am using Hibernate criteria and some restrictions:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getEntityClass(), "remark");
        criteria.createAlias("remark.inspectionTrip", "inspection")
                .createAlias("inspection.laboratory", "laboratory")
                .createAlias("inspection.tripSector", "sector")
                .createAlias("sector.stageList", "stage");

        if (statisticsFilter.getSector() != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("sector.id", statisticsFilter.getSector().getId()));
        }
        if (statisticsFilter.getStage() != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("stage.id", statisticsFilter.getStage().getId()));
        }
e.t.c...
```

Everything works fine. All result set is parsed, and all the entities are loaded from database to my GUI according to the search criteria.

But now, I need to do filtering by date.

For example, I need to select entities in only some year, or in some specific month of that year. 
I was trying to do some kind of this (that was my first and incorrect variant to solve this task):

```
if (statisticsFilter.getDate() != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("inspection.beginDate", statisticsFilter.getDate() "));
        }
```

To solve this issue, I can't  use the Date object, because according [to this nuance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5790681/5331196) it would not be correct, because my date object from JavaFX date picker will be for example '2016-04-23 00:00:00.0000000000' and in my database there is the date '2016-04-23 19:20:23.707000000' and it's not the same.

Then, I have started to make Hibernate sqlRestriction for my HSQLDB, but I can't find the correct way to do this.
(In simple MySQL,e.t.c. integrations there was no such problems, I have always used query as usual and it always worked fine, but in HSQLDB there are some kind of specific aliases and specific query creation rules:

My last test-variant (which is also isn't correct and which gave me an exception) is this:

```
if (statisticsFilter.getDate() != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("remark.beginDate like '2016%'"));
        }
```

Can you please show some small and correct example to create Hibernate criteria sqlRestriction  for HSQLDB for dates using LIKE and also considering the fact that I am using aliases?

(I searched through many different options on the matter, but unfortunately did not find a suitable example to solve the problem.)

Comment: HSQLDB (like many other DB's) does not allow you to use LIKE with dates. Use range criteria as suggested by the answer you linked to.

Comment: Thank you fredt. I guess I didn't understand the answer correctly. I will try this solution.