# How to get latest record from postgresql db?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I am using Hibernate+ postgreql database.Also I have used session for CRUD operation.I completed insert operation successfully.I need to know how to get latest record from entity.

```
 @Repository
 @Transactional
 public class IncidentsDAOImpl extends BaseDAO implements IncidentsDAO{
 @Override
 public Incidents getLatestRecord(String roleId) {
 Incidents obj=new Incidents ();
 List<Incidents> incidents = null;
 incidents = (List<Incidents >) getSession()
                .createCriteria(Incidents .class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("roleId", roleId))
               .add(<how to add lastupdate query---------------------->);
    obj=(incidents != null && !incidents .isEmpty()) ? incidents 
                .get(0) : null;
    return obj;
}
```

how to add lastupdate query?

Comment: Hint: in plain SQL, you're looking for `ORDER BY lastupdated LIMIT 1`.

Comment: you have lastupdate attribute in your model ??

Comment: yes @Mohamed Nabli

Answer (score 0):

try this example :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
    String myDate = "17-04-2011";
    // Create date 17-04-2011 - 00h00
    Date minDate = formatter.parse(myDate);
    // Create date 18-04-2011 - 00h00 
    // -> We take the 1st date and add it 1 day in millisecond thanks to a useful and not so known class
    Date maxDate = new Date(minDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
    Conjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();
    // The order date must be >= 17-04-2011 - 00h00
    and.add( Restrictions.ge("orderDate", minDate) );
    // And the order date must be < 18-04-2011 - 00h00
    and.add( Restrictions.lt("orderDate", maxDate) );
```

source : [Hibernate Criteria for Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790602/hibernate-criteria-for-dates)

Answer (score 0):

I have done using following approach.

```
           @Repository
           @Transactional
           public class IncidentsDAOImpl extends BaseDAO implements IncidentsDAO{
           @Override
           public Incidents getLatestRecord(String roleId) {
           List<Incidents> obj=new ArrayList<Incidents>();
           try{
           Criteria criteria = getSession()
           .createCriteria(Incidents.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("roleId", roleId))
            .addOrder( Order.desc("lastUpdatedOn"));
             obj=criteria.list();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
return (obj!= null && !obj.isEmpty()) ? obj.get(0): null;
}
```