# org.hibernate.exception.DataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: java, hibernate

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
criteria.addOrder(OrderBySqlFormula
                                 .sqlFormula("CASE WHEN to_char(to_date('"
                                              + sdf.format(new Date())
                                              + "'), '') between START_DATE and END_DATE THEN '1' else to_char(END_DATE) END DESC"));
```

This is criteria clause works fine with windows environment but gives the below error when we deploy on production, production envirnment is linux and country is also differnet from local environment :
 org.hibernate.exception.DataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

```
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6277.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1962)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.scroll(Loader.java:2519)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.scroll(CriteriaLoader.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.scroll(SessionImpl.java:1493)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.scroll(CriteriaImpl.java:388)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be passing dates as strings to the query; that's the root of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Criteria for Dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790602/hibernate-criteria-for-dates)

Comment: Avoided passing date as string then also same problem. I just kept  "new Date()"

Comment: Please post the code you tried with. Did you look at the question I linked to?

Comment: Yes, the above code is the latest one ...I have edited that!

Comment: Actually, when I edit the date  format as below :SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");  instead ("dd/MM/yy");

Then locally also giving same exception as production, it means on production as well the date format is not proper. So which format should I give which will fit for linux & windows env also?

Comment: Anyone has any idea on this?