# Date query with JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I need help to make a data query with CriteriaBuilder, I'll leave the code here but it doesn't seem to work. I also need to know how to make a query when the field is in an Object list.

```
public List<Contenido> getAll(Class<Contenido> clase, Map predicados, int offset, int limit, String orderField, int ordenamiento, List<Long> categorias) {
    final List<Predicate> andPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Contenido> cq = cb.createQuery(Contenido.class);
    Root<Contenido> contenido = cq.from(Contenido.class);
    cq.select(contenido);
    Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();
    //this works
    if (predicados.get("titulo") != null) {
        andPredicates.add(cb.and(cb.like(contenido.<String>get("titulo"), "%" + predicados.get("titulo") + "%")));
    }
     //this works
    if (predicados.get("subtitulo") != null) {
        andPredicates.add(cb.and(cb.like(contenido.<String>get("subtitulo"), "%" + predicados.get("subtitulo") + "%")));
    }
    //this works
    if (predicados.get("descripcion") != null) {
        andPredicates.add(cb.and(cb.like(contenido.<String>get("descripcion"), "%" + predicados.get("descripcion") + "%")));
    }
    //doesn't work, Object list query
    if (predicados.get("categoria") != null) {
        andPredicates.add(cb.and(contenido.<List<Categoria>>get("categorias").<String>get("nombre").in(predicados.get("categoria"))));

    }
    //doesn't work (Date query)
    if (predicados.get("fecha") != null) {
        ParameterExpression<Date> param = cb.parameter(Date.class, "fecha");
        andPredicates.add(cb.equal(contenido.<Date>get("fecha"), param));
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify about "doesn't seem to work". In any case, you usually don't want to compare SQL `DATE`s by equality (because you would need to hit the correct timestamp with one-second-precision); instead you often want to use a date interval (as exemplified [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5790681/905488)).

Comment: Thanks Mick, Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: Did you have a look at the answer I linked to above?

Comment: Yes, but Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: @GuidoFranzini Why not answer the question ... what is "doesn't seem to work"? Where is the error? What happens when you execute the query ? what SQL is invoked?